# How to get a view in runtime when using socket.io in android?

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

I have an android application in frontend side and node js socket in backend.

There is a list of Chats in activity that I get them from `socket.on` event.

Every item in this list has a customview in it , I need to update this customview with different values when a socket event is received.

How can I do that?

Here is My Code When getting the list of chats:

```
final Handler mHandler04 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            mHandler04.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SocketManager.getInstance().getSocket().on("allchatres", new Emitter.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(final Object... args) {
                            g.context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) args[0];
                                    Log.d(TAG, "run: " + jsonArray);
                                        try {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                                createView(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("body"));
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

And Here is My Createview Code:

```
private void createView(final String title, final String body) {
    customViewChat = new customViewChat(g.context);
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    customViewChat.txtCsTitle.setText(title);
    customViewChat.txtCsBody.setText(body);
    LinearLayoutItemHolder.addView(customViewChat, layoutParams);
    customViewChat.btnJoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(g.context, DetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("title", title);
            i.putExtra("body", body);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

But When i want to update customview in the list like this :

```
int count = LinearLayoutItemHolder.getChildCount() ;
Log.d(TAG,"child count : " + count) ;
for(int i = 0 ;i<count ; i++)
{
    View v = LinearLayoutItemHolder.getChildAt(i) ;

}
```

I see the below result in logcat:

```
child count : 0
```

How can i get every customview in LinearLayoutItemHolder  ?

I Want to change customView Values in another socket.on event but I can't.

I searched a lot but haven't found anything useful.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: What is g.context here? I want to know where you define object g?

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan That is just the current context , i save the context of fragment in a static variable in g class

Comment: Thats not a good approach that is creating issue here. That will result in memory leak. I think here you have issue regarding context. You cannot use static context for new views. Each view has its own context. So resolve context issue your problem will solve.

Comment: I use this approach because i'm using fragment , and when i leave a fragment and back again , application goes to crash when  i say getActivity().runOnUiThread , So I Saved the context @M.SaadLakhan

Comment: When you create fragment pass activity context to fragment and use that context also if you need reference to activity then you can pass activity to your fragment and in constructor of fragment set this context and activity as private member and then use this context and reference to parent activity. I hope you understand what I am trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the best method to acheive my goal: using RecyclerView!

I had some dificulties using custom views so I used recycler view instead.